# add values to first array for each matching ID in the second array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays like this:

**Array1**

```
$array1 = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            'ID' => 101,
            'Code' => 1075,
            'Date' => '2012-03-03 17:13:12.433'
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            'ID' => 103,
            'Code' => 175,
            'Date' => '2012-09-05 20:30:02.217'
        ),

    2 => Array
        (
            'ID' => 109,
            'Code' => 178,
            'Date' => '2012-07-05 20:30:02.217'
        )

);
```

**Array2**

```
$array2 = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            'Amount' => 1234,
            'ID' => 101
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            'Amount' => 5656,
            'ID' => 101
        ),
    2 => Array
        (
            'Amount' => 1342,
            'ID' => 103
        ),

    3 => Array
        (
            'Amount' => 0,
            'ID' => 0
        )

);
```

I'm using the code below to perform a join on the two arrays :

```
$arr2 = array_column($array2, "ID");

$finalArray = array();
foreach($array1 as $arr){
    $key = array_search($arr['ID'], $arr2);
    if($key ===false){
        $key = array_search(0, $arr2);
    }
    unset($array2[$key]['ID']);
    $finalArray[] =     array_merge($arr,$array2[$key]);
}

print_r($finalArray);
```

The current output using the code above is :

**finalArray**

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 101
            [Code] => 1075
            [Date] => 2012-03-03 17:13:12.433
            [Amount] => 1234 //considers only the first entry of ID 101
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 103
            [Code] => 175
            [Date] => 2012-09-05 20:30:02.217
            [Amount] => 1342
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 109
            [Code] => 178
            [Date] => 2012-07-05 20:30:02.217
            [Amount] => 0
        )

)
```

But since in **array2** there are **two entries for ID 101 but the code above only takes the first match for a matching ID**.
The expected output is :

**Desired Output**

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 101
            [Code] => 1075
            [Date] => 2012-03-03 17:13:12.433
            [Amount] => 1234 //amount for first entry of ID 101
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 101
            [Code] => 1075
            [Date] => 2012-03-03 17:13:12.433
            [Amount] => 5656//amount for second entry of ID 101
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 103
            [Code] => 175
            [Date] => 2012-09-05 20:30:02.217
            [Amount] => 1342
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 109
            [Code] => 178
            [Date] => 2012-07-05 20:30:02.217
            [Amount] => 0
        )

)
```

I'm not able to figure out what loop to use.
The code should add rows for each matching ID of array2.
How do I modify my current code such that it gives me the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr2 = array_column($array2, "ID");

$finalArray = array();
foreach($array1 as $arr){

    //Get the index of ID which exist in array2. And store in search variable.
    $search = array_keys($arr2, $arr['ID']);

    if(!$search){
        //If ID not exit in array-2, get the index of that ID and store in search variable. 
         $key = array_search(0, $arr2);
         $search[0] = $key;
         unset($array2[$key]['ID']);
    }

    //Fetch search item and merge.
    foreach($search as $value){
        $finalArray[] =  array_merge($arr,$array2[$value]);
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($finalArray);
```

Comment: yea I'll try it

Answer (score 1):

Make the result array an associative array keyed by ID. You can copy the element of the first array to the result, then add the amounts from the second array.

```
$finalResult = [];
foreach ($array1 as $arr) {
    $finalResult[$arr['ID']] = $arr;
}
foreach ($array2 as $row) {
    $id = $row['ID'];
    unset($row['ID']);
    foreach ($row as $col => $value) {
        if (empty($finalResult[$id][$col])) {
            $finalResult[$id][$col] = $value;
        } else {
            $finalResult[$id][$col] += $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to type the column name because there can be any number of columns. I pass the ID only other columns get added dynamically

Comment: I've updated it to loop over all the columns in `$array2` and add them all up.